# how to arrange first line of text file as key, next line as value, and the line afterwards as second value until empty line, then repeat again

Tags: python, python-3.x

programming noob here.

I have a cars.text file seperated by lines which I need to convert into a dictionary and here is the format of the text file(please note there is an empty line between each car record, between the car name and the previous line ):

```
Honda

10/11/2010

blue

strong and sturdy

breaks down occasionally
    

Toyota

20/15/2005

indigo

big and spacious


Maserati

10/10/2009

silver

fast and furious

expensive to maintain

accident prone
```

Here is what I have done

```
cars={}
with open('cars.txt', 'r') as f:
  for line in f.readlines():
    car_name=line[0]
    car_date=datetime.line[1]
    car_info=line[2:]
    print(line)
    
f.close()
```

but the code constantly returns a syntax error
What I am trying to do is to make the first line of each paragraph the key, the second line the first value in DateTime format, and the third line until the next empty line the second value, for example:

```
cars={'Honda':['10/11/2010','''blue
strong and sturdy
breaks down occasionally'''],'Toyota':['20/15/2005','''indigo
 big and spacious'''],'Maserati':['10/10/2009','''silver
fast and furious
expensive to maintain
accident prone''']
```

Comment: You dont need `f.close()` because you are opening the file using context manager

Comment: Are all lines seperated by an empty line? And then do you have an extra empty line before every new car?

Comment: there is only an empty line between each new car :)

Comment: kind of like paragraphs i guess

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need. First, read the file and use `splitlines()` method to make a list of all the lines. Then, turn this list into a list of lists where every sublist contains one paragraph.

```
with open('cars.txt') as f:
    names = f.read().splitlines()

l = []
s = []
for i in names:
    if i == "":
        l.append(s)
        s = []
    else:
        s.append(i)
l.append(s)
```

The output will look like this:

```
[['Honda', '10/11/2010', 'blue', 'strong and sturdy', 'breaks down occasionally'], ['Toyota', '20/15/2005', 'indigo', 'big and spacious'], ['Maserati', '10/10/2009', 'silver', 'fast and furious', 'expensive to maintain', 'accident prone']]
```

Then you can simply put that data in your `cars` dictionary.

```
cars = {}
for data in l:
    car_name = data[0]
    car_date = data[1]
    car_info = '\n'.join(data[2:])
    cars[car_name] = [car_date, car_info]

print(cars)
```

Comment: you are my hero

Answer (score 0):

You can get it done this way too:

> First remove all the blank lines

```
with open('filename', 'r+') as fd:
    lines = fd.readlines()
    fd.seek(0)
    fd.writelines(line for line in lines if line.strip())
    fd.truncate()
```

> Then iterate through the lines, five lines at a time

```
cars={}
with open('filename', 'r') as f:
    lines = [line.rstrip() for line in f]
    for i in range(0,len(lines)-1,5):
        cars[lines[i]] = lines[i+1:i+4]
    
print (cars)
```